# How to get the broker address of Kafka in the app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I use Java, Spring-Boot and Kafka in a project.

```
@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate <String, MyRecord> kt;

private void produce ()
{
    MyRecord mr = new MyRecord ("abc");
    ProducerRecord <String, MyRecord> pr = new ProducerRecord <String, MyRecord> ("mytest", "test", mr);
    this.templ.send (pr);   // produce
}

@KafkaListener (topics = "mytest")
private void consume (ConsumerRecord <String, MyRecord> cr)
{   
    // consume
}
```

Here my dependency.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I have it configured as cluster with multiple brokers. How can I find out which broker my app is connected to?

Comment: I dont think you can get any such broker-info from your producer or consumer. That sounds like a possible security issue as well, if that was the case!

Is there a specific reason you need that? if it is just for debugging, you can add more logs and use metrics on your broker side

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your app config, but you can just load the value

```
@Value("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers")
private String bootstrapServers;
```

Otherwise, you'd Autowire the `AdminClient`, then call `describeCluster` and parse it.